# Multiple local Drupal sites for development on WAMPServer?

Tags: installation, distributions

I'm still very new to Drupal.  I'm hoping to create multiple site instances via my local WAMPServer WAMP stack.  I have one.  I realize that Acquia makes this very simple via their DAMP stack, but have heard that it can be very painful upgrading and/or transferring these to a server due to the non-standard paths that Acquia uses for some of its files (some of its modules specifically).  So I'm wondering how I can emulate what DAMP does, albeit without their Dev installer app.  I've searched here and googled, but can't seem to find anything...

Comment: There is nothing else like DAMP stack you can use. Try http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/65178/4471

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a bit off-topic. What you need to do is to setup Apache with [name-based virtual host support](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html). Of course you could place your sites in sub-directories, but you would be much happier with virtual hosts, i.e. one local 'domain' and www root per site.